# Solving $\sqrt {x^2+1} =x-1$ gives an incorrect answer ($x=0$)

Tags: algebra-precalculus, solution-verification

Question

> $$\sqrt {x^2+1} =x-1$$

my attempt

$$ x^2 + 1 = x^2-2x+1 $$
and x=0

by putting the value of 0 = false

Comment: $$\sqrt {x^2+1} =x-1$$
$$\pm\sqrt {0^2+1} =0-1$$
$$-1 =-1$$

Answer (score 3):

The equation has no solution in the real line. The left side of the given equation is non-negative so we need $x-1 \geq 0$. So $x=0$ is not allowed.

Answer (score 1):

On squaring an equation you may obtain extraneous solution,therefore you would have to recheck your solutions with original equation.

Also, $\sqrt {x^2+1} =x-1,$

$x-1 \geq 0$ $\implies$ $x\geq 1$ as the LHS (i.e. $\sqrt {x^2+1}$ ) is always greater than $0$.

Comment: Typesetting tip:  Type `$\sqrt{x}$` to obtain $\sqrt{x}$.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig Thank You.

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.  I have a quibble with your answer.  Squaring an equation *may* produce an extraneous solution (in this case, it certainly does).  Also, you should have written $x - 1 \geq 0 \implies x \geq 1$.  To obtain $\implies$, type `$\implies$`.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig Thank You,I totally agree with you.

Answer (score 0):

Your attemption is not quite right. Note that the left side is a non-negative number, so if you try to do like this, you must guarantee that the right side $x-1 \ge0$, namely $x \ge 1$, at last, you get $x=0$ doesn't satisfy $x\ge 1$, so there is no solution.

Comment: To be more precise, it should be x-1>=1 namely x>=2.